# Compare and count the sparse arrays in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, sparse-matrix

Holla!

I have a list of 60 large-size 2d arrays (30000,30000).

The goal is to compare each array with every other array and count the total number of exactly the same arrays in the entire list.

I am working on this logic, however, it is counting the number of same arrays individually and not what I want:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp

## I am using this dummy setup, to begin with (rather than the large data)

# creating 4 dummy arrays
a = np.zeros((6,6))
a[1,2] = 1
a[2,5] = 1
a[3,2] = 1
a[4,1] = 1
print(a)
b = np.zeros((6,6))
b[1,2] = 1
b[2,5] = 1
b[3,2] = 1
b[4,1] = 1

c = np.zeros((6,6))
c[1,3] = 1
c[2,5] = 1
d = np.zeros((6,6))
d[1,3] = 1
d[2,4] = 1

# storing the arrays in a list
list2d = [a,b,c,d]

#loop through the list to count the number of arrays with exactly same values
n = len(list2d)
for i in range(n):
    count = 0
    for j in range(n):
        if (list2d[i] == list2d[j]).all() and i != j:
            count += 1
            print('list2d[',i,'] is the same as list2d[',j,']')
        else:
            print('list2d[',i,'] is not the same as list2d[',j,']')

print('total number of same arrays || count = ',count)
```

Another option is working with sparse matrices and storing them in a list. However, I'm not sure whether we can compare or check for equity on the entire list with 60 sparse arrays.

```
# again finalizing a logic on a dummy setup
a_sparse = sp.csr_matrix(a)
b_sparse = sp.csr_matrix(b)
c_sparse = sp.csr_matrix(c)
d_sparse = sp.csr_matrix(d)
print(a_sparse)
# #list of sparse matrices
list_sparse = [a_sparse,b_sparse,c_sparse,d_sparse]
## compare the list of sparse arrays and count the total number of exactly same arrays
## also, print/ store all the equal arrays
```

Any suggestions and/or feedback for getting the correct logic is appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: If you understand how `csr` matrices are stored you can compare properties - shape, nnz for a start.  It may also help to ensure that they are 'canonical' - all zeros removed and column indices are sorted.  Then it's just a matter of testing the main arrays, indptr, indices, and data in that order.

Comment: Great suggestion, `csr` seems good! if you may provide some feedback in the loop logic that would be helpful. As I think the logic I have implemented is correct maybe just a couple of changes would lead me to required output.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT#3:**

Based on your comments, I think this is what you are trying to do.

```py
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

def convert_to_tuple(mat):
    x = tuple(np.flatnonzero(mat)) + mat.shape
    return (x)

def get_replicates(id, mat, mat_list):
    replicates = 0
    
    #Remove the relevant matrix from mat_list to avoid checking the reference against itself
    del mat_list[id]
    
    # Create a tuple of the reference matrix
    ref = convert_to_tuple(mat)
    print(id, ":",  ref)
    
    # Check how many replicates of the reference matrix there are
    for m in mat_list:
        s = set()
        s.add(convert_to_tuple(m))
        s.add(ref)
        replicates += (-len(s)+2)
    
    # Replace the matrix into mat_list
    mat_list.insert(id, mat)
    
    return replicates    
    

# Generate a number of sparse matrices
# a=b
# c=d=e=f=g
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
a = np.zeros((6,6))
a[1,2] = 1
a[2,5] = 1
a[3,2] = 1
a[4,1] = 1

b = deepcopy(a)

c = np.zeros((6,6))
c[1,3] = 1
c[2,5] = 1

d = deepcopy(c)
e = deepcopy(c)
f = deepcopy(c)
g = deepcopy(c)


# storing the arrays in a list
list2d = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]


# Identify the number of replicates
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
number_of_replicates  = [get_replicates(i, arr, list2d) for i, arr in enumerate(list2d)]
    

# Print the number of replicates 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for i, reps in enumerate(number_of_replicates):
    print(f"Sparse Array {i} has {reps} replicates")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 : (8, 17, 20, 25, 6, 6)
1 : (8, 17, 20, 25, 6, 6)
2 : (9, 17, 6, 6)
3 : (9, 17, 6, 6)
4 : (9, 17, 6, 6)
5 : (9, 17, 6, 6)
6 : (9, 17, 6, 6)

Sparse Array 0 has 1 replicates
Sparse Array 1 has 1 replicates
Sparse Array 2 has 4 replicates
Sparse Array 3 has 4 replicates
Sparse Array 4 has 4 replicates
Sparse Array 5 has 4 replicates
Sparse Array 6 has 4 replicates
```

The top part of the output shows the what each matrix looks like after being converted to a tuple. The tuple contains the index of each `1` within the matrix, and the **shape** of each matrix `6,6` is appended to the end.

From the output you can see that:

```
array a and b - have 1 replicate each
arrays c,d,e,f,g - have 4 replicates each
```

Comment: Why on earth do you convert the input array to strings? It seems crazy to me: it should be very inefficient (most of the time should be spent on very slow integer to unicode string conversion). Not to mention Python lists are generally pretty slow compared to Numpy arrays.

Comment: From what I understand, there won't be many ones in the sparse arrays, so the string conversion should not take that long.. I could not think of any other way of doing it - but I am happy to learn from other answers :)

Comment: Using a raw bytearray containing raw data (ie. no string conversion) could be a better option (it should be much faster but still slow). Since the items are sparse arrays, it should be better to use Scipy sparse matrices and compare the nnz and indices content rather than the whole matrix full of zeros (and 1 billion items). Using a set is a good idea.

Comment: The edited part looks good! However, I am trying to work around an exception in this case. If there are multiple arrays/tuples in the list with more than one unique array/tuple, this doesn't seem to be working as required. If you may please suggest or edit this to work for this exception case, that would be highly appreciated. For the exception case, you may try this: use the same arrays `[a,b,c,d]` as defined in the very beginning, but make sure in this case, `c` and `d` are also identical, another identical set as `a` and `b`

Comment: In addition, I appreciate your work with `(30000,30000)` matrix, however, to begin with, my main goal is to get the logic work for a dummy setup as depicted in `[a,b,c,d]`. Feel free to add in couple of extra arrays with different set of non-zero indices to check for exceptions. :)

Comment: I seem to get the right results - but had to adjust slightly to accommodate the examples from the beginning.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate your edit#2. I would, however, like to clarify a possible misunderstanding here. What I am expecting is the total count of unique set of identical matrices from a list. I was thinking of a way that if I can set `a` as reference matrix and in the list search of its identical pairs, then set `b` as ref and repeat, the `c` as ref and finally `d` as ref. In this case, if the count is initiated as 0, the output may look like, `For ref as a: 1` and it will be the same for `b,c and d` in this case.

Comment: Ok - I hope this satisfies your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably not choose to fiddle with array stuff in weird ways. I definitely would not cast sparse matrices to dense for this, as doing that directly for 60 of these 30k x 30k things would require 450GB of memory or so. Just check everything as it is.

Set up the problem (so that there are 40 unique matrices and 20 matrices which are not unique), and use Counters instead of reinventing that wheel:

```
from collections import Counter
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

list_of_arrays = [sparse.rand(200,200,density=np.random.uniform(0.025, 0.075),format='csr') for _ in range(50)]

for i in range(10):
    list_of_arrays.append(list_of_arrays[i])
```

Exclude any matrices which have unique shapes or unique nnz (as they're trivial to check):

```
# Check NNZ
nnz_counter = Counter([x.nnz for x in list_of_arrays])
non_unique_arrays = [x for x in list_of_arrays if nnz_counter[x.nnz] > 1]

# Check Shape
shape_counter = Counter([x.shape for x in non_unique_arrays])
non_unique_arrays = [x for x in non_unique_arrays if shape_counter[x.shape] > 1]
```

Use numpy array views + hashing to compare arrays to find identical arrays (this returns a list of True if the array has a duplicate and False otherwise).

```
# Check a list of arrays for duplicates by hashing
def array_hash(arrays):
    return [hash(x.view) for x in arrays]

def array_hash_duplicates(arrays):
    hashes = array_hash(arrays)
    hash_counter = Counter(hashes)
    return [True if hash_counter[x] > 1 else False for x in hashes]
```

Now apply that check to the matrix indptr, indices, and data arrays in order, removing any matrices which are unique after each check.

```
# Check indptr, indices, and data in order
non_unique_arrays = [
    x
    for x, y in zip(
        non_unique_arrays,
        array_hash_duplicates([x.indptr for x in non_unique_arrays])
    )
    if y
]

non_unique_arrays = [
    x
    for x, y in zip(
        non_unique_arrays,
        array_hash_duplicates([x.indices for x in non_unique_arrays])
    )
    if y
]

duplicates = Counter(array_hash([x.data for x in non_unique_arrays]))
n_duplicates = sum(x - 1 for x in duplicates.values())

>>> n_duplicates
10
```

This results in a list of matrices which are non-unique (so at least one other matrix is identical in the list). It's possible to have multiple non-unique matrices which are not the same, of course.

Note that this is inefficient if you expect the list to be duplicates of the same python object, not just different matrices with the same values. That would be easy to solve another way.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed response. As mentioned, the goal is to count unique sets of identical sparse matrices as in the original data I am expecting a very low number of uniquely identical set of arrays from the list of sparse arrays. To put things into perspective, I'm expecting the count to be not more than single digit out of the 60 - (30k,30k) matrices. If you may please comment on getting the count of unique sets of from the dummy setup, it would be helpful

Comment: "Count the unique sets of identical sparse matrices" is ambiguous. You would like to count the number of unique matrices in a list - that's one number. You'd like to have a number of duplicates in the list for every element - that's a list of numbers, one for each matrix.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you mentioned in the latter part of of comment i.e. "number of duplicates in the list for every element - that's a list of numbers, one for each matrix". For instance, with dummy setup of `[a,b,c,d]`, it would look like: `a = 1`# of duplicates (since a==b) and so on for b,c and d as well. I am unable to put a logic for this! If you may have any idea or suggestion, would love to try that.